# Website "jumps" up and covers input when typing with iPhone's virtual keyboard

Tags: html, iphone

I've a website with a textarea at the bottom. When I focus the textarea, the keyboard slides up and pushes the website up so I can see the textarea. As soon as I start typing, the website jumps back down and now the keyboard overlays the input and I'm not able to see what I'm typing.

Comment: Can we see an example or some code?

Comment: A shot in the dark with no code example, but if it starts as soon as you begin typing, are you using an onkeypress() function or something of that nature?

Comment: It's company code, but I try to describe it: it's React and it uses react-autosize-textarea. And to answer Jeremy, yes an onKeyDown is used.